# Asus PN64 (intel i7-12700H) not going to sleep

Tags: suspend, standby

I've got a new computer : Asus PN64, core i7-12700H. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it.

I'm a regular Ubuntu user for more than 10 years, on laptops and servers.

Sometimes I had some trouble with laptops waking from sleep mode correctly. This time I can't manage to get my PN64 to go to sleep. When I enter `systemctl suspend` on the command line (or bind it to a keyboard shortcut), the computer *seems* to go to sleep, the screens go black and enter sleep, but the computer fan keeps spinning.

Also, after resume, `dmesg` shows a bunch of errors related to `drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_tc.c` They seems to me to be kernel traces but not sure.

Any clue as to what to do to get this computer to sleep correctly? I am using a worked-around at the moment by using hibernate but the resume time is not ideal.

Thanks !

PS : tried with stock kernel 5.15, and with 6.0.1 (Ubuntu Mailine Kernel installer doesn't  offer other 5.XX versions at the moment !?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the answer right under my eyes in the dmesg log :
The system was going to s2idle instead of s3 standby.
So I tested with writing `deep` to `/sys/power/mem_sleep` and it worked !

Just had to set the boot setting `mem_sleep_default=deep` and it persisted over reboots.